# getQuery() How to in python

Tags: python, get, python-3.3

I am having trouble understanding how to do this. The purpose of this is going to have a different module call to this function have it return the correct url which will than be downloaded and have things extracted from it.

`getQuery(location)` returns a URL containing a GET query to retrieve the weather from wunderground.com for a given location.

For example, `getQuery('Princeton, WV')` returns the URL

```
http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/hdfForecast?query=Princeton%2C+WV
```

Comment: you question isn't clear. please add some info on what is the problem and what's not working.

Comment: what library are you using? and what are you trying to accomplish/whats not working?

Comment: Feed it a dictionary? `{'getkey' : 'value'}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python retrieving information from the web for a weather widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005141/python-retrieving-information-from-the-web-for-a-weather-widget)

Comment: C'mon. Now you're going to ask an individual question for every function in your assignment?

Answer (score 2):

```
def getQuery(location):
   # return your root url plus the location encoded using quote_plus
   # http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus
   pass
```